# Adding any control at the Horizontal Scrollbar's blank area when having frozen DataGrid columns

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

Hi,

I have a `FrozenColumnCount = 3` always with `HorizontalScrollBar` visible. Now, I have a requirement to add controls in the blank area (left of the scroll bar) -- See the RED highlighted area in the image.

How can I add any control there ? It will be great if something of this sort can be achieved via XAML (ControlTemplates) ? I am using the standard `WPF v4.0 datagrid` in my application.

> NB: The sample can be downloaded from here -
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/31/wpf-datagrid-frozen-row-sample.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with this documentation of [DataGrid Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Notice the part of the template which looks like this

```
              <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"
                       ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                       Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                       Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                       Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
          </Grid>
```

This portion defines the bottom scrollbar area in the DataGrid. Notice the binding to NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset -- that value determines the width of the empty left area.

You could copy the whole DataGrid template into a style in the application resources in the project. Then, insert your own named horizontal StackPanel with Grid.Column="0" there (a sibling to the ScrollBar), you can then add your own child buttons, text, etc. as children of that new StackPanel.

Answer (score 1):

you have two way to resolve it.

a. install snoop, find out to what element this area belongs and see if it can be accessed in a template (I hope you know how to create a copy of template in Blend).

b. process size / move events and place a control above this area simply by positioning your controls precisely as if they were in the grid template...

Comment: No, I do not know the BLEND part. This 'offset' area is automatically created based on FrozenColumnCount in the run-time. I don't think I can position any control unless I know how and where to position (in the runtime).

Comment: open the control in blend - template - edit copy. you will get full copy of the data grid for example... re: position - sure, my advice is based on assumption you will have to either dig it out with snoop again and walking the visual tree in run-time. this is a lot of work but it is all doable... I doubt there is a 'magic' solution will be presented so I suggest you start digging now